# how to provide tether/anything-else globally in my meteor1.3 typescript project?

Tags: meteor, typescript, webpack, angular2-meteor

I'm hardly trying to get my existing ng2-prototype running in a meteor1.3 setup. So far i was building the prototype with webpack, and there is a provide plugin to make things like jQuery or Tether available during module building:

```
plugins: [
  new ProvidePlugin({
     $: "jquery",
     jQuery: "jquery",
     "window.jQuery": "jquery",
     "window.Tether": "tether"
  })
]
```

As you can see, i did the same with "tether", since it's still the lib needed by bootstrap 4 alpha.

Now i'm wondering how i could achieve the same in my meteor1.3 project..? As written in the changelogs of the package "angular2-meteor", it is using webpack under the hood now to build everything.

[angular2-meteor changelog](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

So, it should be possible to use the same provide plugin again in meteor1.3, right? But... how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the github issue threads of "angular2-meteor":

> there are multiple ways: you could install https://atmospherejs.com/coursierprive/tether, or, 
>   since Meteor 1.3 prefers NPM now, you could install Tether NPM and require it before you use bootstrap 4, or, if you want more control and modularity, you could create own local package (in the packages folder) with all dependencies (added from NPMs) you need including Tether (similar to the way angular2-runtime done in this repo).

i will try this out and i'm already sure this will do the trick :) many thx @barbatus ;)

Update:

Ok i'm going with the npm package solution, i had tether installed already. If you don't have it, do this first:

```
npm install --save tether
```

Now, the single `require` statement won't be enough.. bootstrap 4 which i'm trying to include completely is asking for a `window.Tether` function. So i ended up doing this:

```
let Tether = require('tether');
window.Tether = Tether;

// import all bootstrap javascript plugins
require('bootstrap');
```

Cool is, there is also a typings definition file for it now, just add it by running:

```
typings install --save --ambient tether
```

After adding it to the window global context, the errors are gone... but ok, the solution trough the webpack provide plugin feels still cleaner -> it will provide the Tether object for each module separately during build, so it won't end up living in the window global context after all. But i'm just lucky to have it running now :)

PS: jQuery is provided anyways by meteor, that's the reason it is already enough to get it running by just including tether alone.

Update: yeah jQuery is included by default - but it is just a package in your /.meteor/packages file ;)

Comment: Hi @jebbie, if you succeed and explained it [here](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0-socially/issues/44), that will be awesome!

Comment: hi @HongboMiao, i've tried the solution by installing the tether npm package and just require it before i'll require bootstrap, i guess it works, the error is gone.. i'm stucked now with my templateUrl's - my meteor app won't serve the GET requests for the files.. i guess i'm missing an api.addFiles but, i only know that so far from packages.. investigating further ^^

Comment: awesome, to add templates relatively in the right way, use moduleId: http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/

Comment: I got no luck, I will wait a few more days until angular2-meteor1.3 comes out. This is your question and answer, you need accept by yourself. haha

Comment: okey, yeah i destroyed my setup too on the weekend by updating to rc13 and to latest angular2-meteor.. but i guess it is based on new beta.12 of angular in my case - hahaha, didn't remember about those rules when i answer my own question ^^